# How do I run this JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, content-type, jsom

I was looking for ways I can automatically change the content type  of my files inside SharePoint online.
I go a code from  [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/264274/84042)

I'm not sure how the code is supposed to work. Added a Webpart, scripteditor on my document library.

At the part in the code where is says contenttypeId, I've pasted the content type id I want the files to be change to.

Nothing is happening. Not sure how the code is supposed to work.

Here is the code:

```
 var contenttypeId = '0x01040005B1FCA568800F4FB4162C7A09742E67';
var lisTitle = "TestNewList";
var listitemId = 1;

UpdateListItem(lisTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId);

function UpdateListItem(listTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    oListItem = oList.getItemById(listitemId);
    oListItem.set_item('ContentTypeId', contenttypeId);
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem, 'Id', 'Title', 'ContentTypeId');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            var listsInfo = '';
            listsInfo += oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\t' + oListItem.get_item('ContentTypeId');
            console.log(listsInfo.toString());
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: First thing is check your developer console and see if method is getting called. If so, is it going in success delegate or failure.. what is error message...you have to just use debugging technique to check for issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the code snippet, need to enable the Content Type Management for the library and add the Content Type needed in library settings,for example, I want to set Content Type "Images" for Item 7 which is an image:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, make sure passed valid list name and item Id in the code snippet, this is my test snippet(item Id: 7, list name: doc2):

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");
function runCode(){   
    var contenttypeId = '0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F2140047E654AF66AF2C4699BC331533868D61';
    var lisTitle = "doc2";
    var listitemId = 7;

    UpdateListItem(lisTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId);
}
function UpdateListItem(listTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    oListItem = oList.getItemById(listitemId);
    oListItem.set_item('ContentTypeId', contenttypeId);
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem, 'Id', 'Title', 'ContentTypeId');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            var listsInfo = '';
            listsInfo += oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\n' + oListItem.get_item('ContentTypeId');
            alert(listsInfo.toString());
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        })
    );
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What is listitle`= doc2 ? the name of the file who's content type you want to change ? and what about listitemId = 7 ?

Comment: listtitleis the document library name, and listItemId is the item Id. Both can be got in the library, please check the capture updated in the post.

Comment: I followed zour steps, writing the document library name, the item id and also giving the content type id but when I stop editing I get this error. Null:0x010109005A...

Comment: You will need to set value for the library item title field as listsInfo is getting the title field value and then content type id. Otherwise, it will be null. And this means you have set the content type for the specific item correctly, you can check in Properties.

Comment: I will update the capture to make you understand clearly.

Comment: So this code only changes the content type of one file ? not sure If I'm understanding you right. I have this file that has this content type . On  the code I pasted the ContentType Id to which I want the file to be updated. I put the library name under listTitle and file id under listitemId

Comment: Yeah, if you read the function name UpdateListItem and parameter, you will understand more clearly, this function is to change the content type for a file item....

Comment: I think you could refer my capture above, it almost provide all the parameter how they coming and the meaning they stand for.

Comment: thank you. However I'm looking for a way to change the content type ID of multiple files without using Powershell

Comment: You are welcome, for the new question for changing multiple files content type, I suggest you could create a new thread so we could focus on the new question. For this question, if it help you to find out the usgae of the code snippet in original question, you could accept as answer so that it could also help others who stuck with the same question in the forum.

Comment: I marked is as answered. thank you. It will probably be helpful for people that just want to change the content type of one file even though its probably faster to do it manually. I also created a new question regarding  changing the content type of multiple items: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/264556/84042